# Trying to render ggmap plot in R Shiny dynamically but receiving only blank image

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, gis, ggmap

i am working on a complex R-Shiny application for geoanalysis. As part of this I want to dynamically render a ggmap stemen map. As so I ask the user for the Openstreetmap export data (zoom, left, right... see [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=4/20.91/5.83)). With a click on the button I want to build and render the map. Unfortunately the only thing that happens is that I get a blank image. If I use the plot function to render the map in RStudio I am able to see the plot.

What do I have to change to get the map plotted?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$show_map, {
        
        box <- c(
            left = input$left,
            bottom = input$bottom,
            right = input$right,
            top = input$top)
        
        map <- get_stamenmap(
            bbox = box,
            maptype = "terrain",
            zoom = input$zoom
        )
        plot(map) #plot in RStudio
        output$point_map <- renderPlot(map)
    })
    
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        numericInput("top", "North", value = "55.159", width = 75),
        numericInput("bottom", "South", value = "47.2", width = 75),
        numericInput("left", "West", value = "5.768", width = 75),
        numericInput("right", "East", value = "15.216", width = 75),
        numericInput("zoom", "Zoom", value = "7", width = 75, min = 0, max = 18),
        actionButton("show_map", "Show map!")),
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput('point_map')
    )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To actually plot your map you have to call `ggmap(map)` or `plot(map)`, i.e. do

```
output$point_map <- renderPlot(ggmap(map))
```

or

```
output$point_map <- renderPlot(plot(map))
```

in your app.

[image]